# Apply filter to children of tree also

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to filter tree store using this

```
treeStore.filter('name',textField.getValue());
```

it works well **on top level nodes.**

But the filter is not applied to nested nodes.

In other words, say there is some child node deep in the tree called "Hello".
If I type "Hello" in instead of `textField.getValue()` above, it doesn't work. Tree is shown as empty. I rather want "Hello" with all its parents to get shown.

How can I overcome this? (using Ext JS 6).

I tried setting (for treestore) `filterer:'bottomup'` but doesn't help.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me for non-top level nodes:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1g3u

The `Unmatched Child` and `Child` nodes hide when I click the `Filter` button.

Comment: I think this works because your tree starts in expanded way. Try to collapse Root Child and then click the filter. I would like "another child" to show up.

Comment: btw what is /o/ ?

Comment: Did you try commenting out the `expanded` lines and run the fiddle? I did and it worked for me. Ext JS did expand the root node. /o/ is RegExp that I searched for instead of just a string, that has no bearing on filter behavior.

Comment: Why this: store.filter('text', "Another");
, doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't work, try renaming "Root Child", to "rwaar Child" for example,
 and run your code now. See??? "Another child" is not shown anymore

Comment: Added `filterer` to the `TreeStore` and it does. The following fiddle has that node renamed and the `expanded` commented out https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1g42

Comment: This is strange I am pretty sure I was doing same - you can see in my question I mentioned filterer too. Why was not it working with my case? Can it be related that I was retrieving data with proxy??

Comment: btw do you know is there way if by pressing filter it shows Another Child? Now it only expands the Root Child. It doesn't directly show Another child. You have to expand Root Child after filter